# Creating a Phoenix index in Hortonworks Sandbox doesn't work

Tags: hbase, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-phoenix

I followed the documentation, and created in Phoenix 4.2:

```
CREATE VIEW "t20" ( pk VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, "f2"."name" VARCHAR );
```

Then created an index:

```
create index idx on "t20" ("name");
```

(Quoting or unquoting gives the same result)

And getting:

```
ERROR 1029 (42Y88): Mutable secondary indexes must have the hbase.regionserver.wal.codec property set to org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.IndexedWALEditCodec in the hbase-sites.xml
```

Now I've changed this property everywhere before trying to create the index: on the Ambari advanced configuration, directly in /etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml, in the hbase-site.xml of phoenix.

Still the same error message. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the hbase-site directly, your changes won't take effect until you restart the services. But if you restart the services using an Ambari Agent, it will take the Ambari-configured settings for hbase-site. Thus, you need to set the property in the Ambari web console and restart the services through the console as well.